# I need the most efficient C# RSS reader possible

Tags: c#, rss

I am developing an app that will monitor several thousands of feeds from across the web.

I have a simple RSS reader that will do the trick, but I am worried about bandwidth and latency issues - this must be as fast and efficient as possible.

I want an RSS reader/library that polls a feed and checks if it has updated without downloading any content (by analyzing the date header in the response, for example), and using local caching to reduce bandwidth so the entire feed is never re-downloaded.

My important metrics are *minimum bandwidth* and *minimum access latency*. I don't care about memory usage, disk space, processing power etc.

Is there any library out there that does all this automatically?

Answer (score 3):

[Jeff says, do it yourself.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001172.html)

Comment: Normally I would, but this is a problem that I'm 99.9% certain has been tackled and accomplished before, and is not specific to any one implementation. I just want a fast RSS reader - I don't want to reinvent the wheel for this